# Using same variable multiple times in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have researched this and it seems it is complicated or at least not simple to use a variable declared in JavaScript in an HTML document multiple times.

For instance, I have multiple (hundreds) of div's with IMG statements referencing different JPG files. I want to give a path to those files that is the same on each div, and I want to be able to declare the path text in a variable and use it on each line. This would give me the ability to change the path by just changing the variable. The fact that I would be using it multiple times means that "id=" would not work since it can only be used once.

It is a shame there is not a simple way to do this, as I am sure it would be very useful. An example using an IMG in a DIV would be helpful.

Example:

```
<div class="column">
<img src="SomePathtoFile/images/1.jpg" class="myimages"      
  onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
</div>
```

I want the "SomePathtoFile"  to be a variable used in this and all following div's.

Comment: [`base`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) sets a base URL.

Comment: Did you mean something like I have written in the answer section? If it is not so, can you please describe more about this problem?

Comment: There are no variables in HTML. You can have HTML attributes which you then use as variables in JS. But it's unclear what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: This is a built in feature in frameworks like React, Vue and Angular, that creates HTML through javascript. Sadly, it's not something that you can use in an intuitive way with just HTML or HTML+javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on what you're trying to achieve, but looks on the face of it like a job for **[data-attributes](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-data-attributes/)**

You can create them with any name you like: data-link, data-image, data-whatever and then get/set them with JS.

```
<span class="foo" data-info="nice">

// Get
span.dataset.info

// Set
span.dataset.info = "sweet";
```

I'd try to dynamically render the value of the attribute on each div at the same time the div and its content/image is generated, which should give you a clear reference to each.

Hope it helps and that I've understood your question!

Comment: OK can you give me an example using data-attributes to set the path and then use it in my example IMG within the DIV?

Comment: You would use it the same way as you would do with ID. You said in your question you know how to do this with ID so just use data attribute instead of ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```js
var imgVariable = "https://i.ibb.co/8BQcPn4/1.png"
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".column img");
for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    nodeList[i].src = imgVariable;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
    <img src="1.png" alt="first" class="myimages" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor" width="50px">
    <img src="2.png" alt="second" class="myimages" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor" width="50px">
    <img src="3.png" alt="third" class="myimages" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor" width="50px">
</div>
```

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you refer to something called `scoped variable`, it works more js than data attributes, let's see this `scoped variable` example first (run it)

```js
let arr = 'abcdef'.split('')
arr.forEach(x => createButton(x))


function createButton(x) {
  let n = document.createElement('button')
  n.innerHTML = x
  n.addEventListener('click', () => alert(x))
  document.body.append(n)
}
```

and data attribute example

```js
let arr = 'abcdef'.split('')
arr.forEach(x => createButton(x))


function createButton(x) {
  let n = document.createElement('button')
  n.innerHTML = x
  n.dataX=x
  n.addEventListener('click', e => alert(e.target.dataX))
  document.body.append(n)
}
```

---

div/img is no different than button

```js
let arr = 'abcdef'.split('')
arr.forEach(x => createButton(x))


function createButton(x) {
  let d = document.createElement('div')
  let n = document.createElement('img')
  n.alt = x
  n.addEventListener('click', () => alert(x))
  d.append(n)
  document.body.append(d)
}
```

Comment: My application  is NOT a button or clickable item. It is executed in an IMG statement within a DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Closest I've found is to use render html using js. Using the dollar & curly braces to enclose your var.

```
<div id="fileList"></div>
<div id="more"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // local computer path same as html file
    var myPath = "./photos";
    var container = document.getElementById('fileList');
    var div = document.createElement('div');    
    var image = `
        <img src="${myPath}/frog.jpg" class="myimages"
      onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
    `;  
    div.innerHTML = image;
    container.appendChild(div); 

    var otherPath = "https://images.freeimages.com";
    var container = document.getElementById('more');
    var div = document.createElement('div');    
    var image2 = `
        <img src="${otherPath}/images/large-previews/f41/white-tiger-1362375.jpg" class="myimages"
      onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
    `;  
    div.innerHTML = image2;
    container.appendChild(div);     

</script>
```

Comment: I guess I need to give up on this one. The issue here is I have one web page setup to view photos but I want to use that page for different applications, so titles and file paths differ. It would be nice to be able to change that with variables but I see it is not that easy. I can just use search and replace to do it. I also don't understand why this has not be done in HTML. The entire page is  sent to the client and could include static variables that the browser could resolve like $1="some text" and then $1 in the entire document is replaced with that text. Am I missing something?